# mergeMap() RXJS 3 observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I watched a tutorial on how to use mergeMap() on 2 observables but I'm still very unclear on how to use it with more than 2 observables.

Here is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b59tcUwfpWU&t=1s

Here is the code for 3 observables to concatenate three inputs and display dynamically on html.

```js
var input1 = document.querySelector('#input1');
var input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');
var input3 = document.querySelector('#input3');

var span = document.querySelector('span');

var obs1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input1, 'input');
var obs2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input2, 'input');
var obs3 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input3, 'input');


obs1.mergeMap((event1) => {
 return obs2.map((event2) => {
   return event1.target.value + ' ' + event2.target.value;
  });
}).mergeMap((result) => {
 return obs3.map((event3) => {
   return result + ' ' + event3.target.value;
  });
}).subscribe((combinedValue) => {
 console.log(combinedValue);
 return span.textContent = combinedValue;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">

<p>Combined value: <span></span></p>
```

My problem here is that when i type in the first and second inputs, the display does not dynamically show the changes until I enter something into the third input.

My current understanding of mergeMap() is that it flattens a sequence of sequence of observables into a sequence of observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the operator `combineLatest()`.
To make things simpler, I would map the `event.target.value` after each `fromEvent`, and perhaps throw in the `startWith('')` since nothing is happening until the user types.

```js
console.clear()
var input1 = document.querySelector('#input1')
var input2 = document.querySelector('#input2');
var input3 = document.querySelector('#input3');

var span = document.querySelector('span');

var obs1 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input1, 'input')
  .map(e=>e.target.value)
  .startWith('')

var obs2 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input2, 'input')
  .map(e=>e.target.value)
  .startWith('')

var obs3 = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input3, 'input')
  .map(e=>e.target.value)
  .startWith('')

Rx.Observable.combineLatest(obs1,obs2,obs3)
.map(([val1,val2,val3]) => val1 + ' ' + val2 + ' ' + val3) 
.subscribe((combinedValue) => {
 console.log(combinedValue);
 return span.textContent = combinedValue;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.7/Rx.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="input1">
<input type="text" id="input2">
<input type="text" id="input3">

<p>Combined value: <span></span></p>
```